# Jackson parser json setter to take value as string array

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I have below json:

```
    "[{\"movieName\":\"A\",\"Leadactor\":\"\",\"leadActress\":\"\",\"movieTitle\":\"\",\"hero\":\"\",\"heroine\":\"\",\"source\":\"IMDB\"}," +
    "{\"movieName\":\"\",\"Leadactor\":\"\",\"leadActress\":\"\",\"movieTitle\":\"B\",\"hero\":\"B1\",\"heroine\":\"B2\",\"source\":\"Netflix\"}," +
    "{\"movieName\":\"C\",\"Leadactor\":\"C1\",\"leadActress\":\"C2\",\"movieTitle\":\"\",\"hero\":\"\",\"heroine\":\"\",\"source\":\"IMDB\"}," +
    "{\"movieName\":\"D\",\"Leadactor\":\"D1\",\"leadActress\":\"D2\",\"movieTitle\":\"\",\"hero\":\"\",\"heroine\":\"\",\"source\":\"IMDB\"}," +
    "{\"movieName\":\"\",\"Leadactor\":\"\",\"leadActress\":\"\",\"movieTitle\":\"E\",\"hero\":\"E1\",\"heroine\":\"E2\",\"source\":\"Netflix\"}]";
```

I am using jackson parser to map it to a class:

I want movieName and movieTitle to map into Name property in the java class. So i wrote the below class:

```
public static class MovieData {
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;

    @JsonSetter({"movieName"})
    private void setMovieName(final String name) {
            if((name != null) && (! name.equals(""))) {
                    setNameInternal(name);
            }
    }

    @JsonSetter("movieTitle")
    private void setMovieTitle(final String name) {
            if((name != null) && (! name.equals(""))) {
                    setNameInternal(name);
            }
    }

    private void setNameInternal(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
    }
```

}

In my real json there are so many fields like movieName, movieTitle which i want to normalize into a common name.

Is there any simple syntax like the below which can reduce code duplication:

```
public static class MovieData {
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;

 @JsonSetter(value = { "movieName", "movieTitle" })
 private void setName(final String name) {
        if((name != null) && (! name.equals(""))) {
                this.name=name;
        }
}
  }
```

The above code gave me error on jsonSetter:

```
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to String.
```

**EDIT**

If Jackson doesn't support it,  can GSON Support this operation.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not very clear... do you want a list of objects `Movie` with an attribute `name`, which contains the value of either `"movieName"` or `"movieTitle"`? And if, let's say, `"movieName"` has a value, `"movieTitle"` will be always emtpty?

Comment: Have you tried adding multiple annotations to setName, one for movieName and one for movieTitle? Otherwise the solution below with @JsonAnySetter will work.

Comment: @MikO yes i want a list of objects Movie with an attribute name, which contains the value of either movie name or movie title. Yes if movie name has a vlaue then movie title is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@JsonAnySetter`, what it is mean you can find on [Jackson Core (Data-Binding) Annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations) page.

I have created simple bean which is related to your example:

```
class MovieData {

    private static List<String> NAME_PROPERTIES = Arrays.asList("movieName", "movieTitle");

    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    private void parseUnknownProperties(String propertyName, String propertyValue) {
        if (NAME_PROPERTIES.contains(propertyName) && !propertyValue.isEmpty()) {
            this.name = propertyValue;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Now when I deserialize your JSON in this way:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(objectMapper.readValue(json, MovieData[].class)));
```

As result I can see:

```
[A, B, C, D, E]
```

Answer (score 3):

Dont do this much. it is very simple with Gson

create class for your single set record
like

```
class Movie{
    private String movieName;
    private String Leadactor;
    private String leadActress;

    //put getter and setter for your fields
}

in main file
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Movie>>(){}.getType();
List<Movie> data = new Gson().fromJson(json_string,type);
```

Comment: I know about gson. the problem is about normalization. I want movieTitle also to map into movieName;

Comment: Please refrain from asking people to vote/accept your answers. [See this meta post for more information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167155/152134). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You declare the field like `@JsonProperty String[] data`

and use

```
 new ObjectMapper()
      .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
      .readValue(json, YOUT_TYPE.class)
```

So this option make Jackson part both "foo":"bar" and "foo": ["a", "b", "c"].

All you need to do is to merge string array back into the string with right line separators. I do it via Guava `data == null ? null : Jointer.on("\n").join(data)`